# SwiftUI - Check if a value is present in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have an array with several objects each with a name and a password. Elsewhere I have a value and I would like to check if this value is already equal to a name in the array.
In my code, if the value is not equal to a "name" value in the array, I use the add() function.
I have no idea how to do this at all. Do you have any advice or a simple code for me please?

```
struct Object  {
    var name : String
    var password : String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var valeur : String = "x"
    @State var array = [Object]()
    // Let's say it's filled

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {
                if ... {
                    self.addRow()
                }
            }) {
                 Text("Add")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if array.contains(where: { $0.name == someValue }) {`

Comment: Ok this is the solution thank you very much